# JSON value <null> of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I keep getting this issue when I land on the home screen on my app, I'm not 100% why the issue is happening or what could be the cause. I've tried to google this but haven't found anything helpful that could guide me in the right path.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JZ5p.png)

Think it's happening somewhere in this code:

```
const InstaagramEmpty = () => <InstagramUsersEmpty text="No matching users found" />

const InstagramUserItem = (props: { onSelect: () => void, user: InstagramUser }) => {

    //TOOD: user button
    return <AccountContainer onPress={props.onSelect}>
        <AccountImage source={{ uri: props.user.photoUrl }} />
        <Text text={props.user.username} />
    </AccountContainer>
}

// Brinds image/text together
const SelectionContainer = styled(Row)` 
`

const SelectionClear = styled(ButtonIcon)`
    width:45px;
    height:45px; 
`

const InstagramUserSelection = (props: { onSelect: () => void, user: InstagramUser }) => {

    return <Row drop>
        <SelectionContainer>
            <AccountImage source={{ uri: props.user.photoUrl }} />
            <Text text={props.user.username} />
        </SelectionContainer>
        <SelectionClear icon={IconClose} iconTint={Colors.GreyDark} onPress={props.onSelect} />
    </Row>
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code snippet's of where it might be happening?

Comment: @FredAstaire I have no idea where it could be happening but I'll add a place I think it might be a possibility

Answer (score 0):

When your JSON document contains the value null, then that will be translated to an Objective-C object of class NSNull. NSNull is a singleton class; the class method [NSNull null] always returns the only NSNull object that ever exists. If you are given an object of unknown type, you can check whether it is a JSON null value by comparing it with [NSNull null]. if (myJSONObject == [NSNull null]) ...

So your JSON data contains a null value, which becomes [NSNull null], and [NSNull null] cannot be converted to anything. Handle it the same as nil. For example if (myJSONObject == nil || myJSONObject == [NSNull null]) ...